# jQuery datepicker parsing year with one digit

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have jQuery datepicker with dateFormat `d.m.yy` which should parse dates like 1.1.1990 or 31.12.2014. The problem is that the `parseDate()` function parses successfully even date 1.1.1 as 1.1.2014.

My question is - can I restrict somehow the parse to reject such dates? I want only years with four digits to be parsed.

Comment: You can check the input yourself manually using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking before they submit or on change of datepicker like this:

```
var dateReg = /^\d{1,2}([/])\d{1,2}\1\d{4}$/;

if((!yourdate.match(/\S/)) || (!yourdate.match(dateReg)))
{
    //if this is true then
    window.alert("You must enter a valid date");
}
```